# Azure: Can Public PaaS connect to private network via Express Route?

Tags: azure, express, routes, paas

Can Publicly accessible Azure Mobile Services, hosted via PaaS, access a private internal network if there was an existing Express Route setup?

So basically, a user with a Smart Phone calls an Azure Hosted PaaS Mobile Service, the mobile services then communicates, through the Express Route, with objects (like a database or other services) hosted in the private network and then respond to the caller with some of that data.

Is this currently possible using PaaS and an Express Route?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes and it is the Application Service Environment which comes with your own vnet.

Comment: Please elaborate.  A lot.

Answer (score 0):

No this functionality isn't and most likely will not be available for Mobile Services... but not all hope is lost. Azure App Services will provide similar functionality to mobile services and can be "bound" to a vnet... which will enable it to access local resources using express route.

Per the docs, App services can provide...

> Connectivity to your on-premise resources and VPNs using VNet in
>   addition to Hybrid Connections

ref: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-value-prop-migration-from-mobile-services-preview/

Answer (score 0):

For my understanding, Mobile Services - its your "frontend", On Prem - your backend.

If you need to access DB from your code in Mobile Services, you should provide its location (ip, port,...).

How your application will go out to this location, is configured in "network" configuration of your package.

So,

1. First step - configure Express Route
2. Create your vnet and [link it to Express Route](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/expressroute-howto-vnet-portal-classic/)
3. [Update](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBsQFjAAahUKEwjNjZ_j8ubIAhWCzRQKHWV3Bgc&url=https%3A%2F%2Fazure.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdocumentation%2Farticles%2Fweb-sites-integrate-with-vnet%2F&usg=AFQjCNF-Q8uLzqLpL7DWOX3TlyCFmDUBFA&sig2=in9x4zP3XQstk9EnxEBpFQ&bvm=bv.106130839,d.ZWU) your package configuration to use this criated vnet